# Identify this state outline file

Tags: shapefile, data, united-states

Some time back, I came across a site that was offering sets of US state outlines that were intended to be attractive/artistic rather than geographically accurate. I only have this copy of the outline of Georgia from one of the sets, and I've lost track of the original site. Can anyone identify it?

[image: Georgia state outline]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like it could be from the [Project Linework](http://www.projectlinework.org/) website. Specifically, the "Angular" or "Twenty Seventy" datasets.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  It is from the "Twenty Seventy" dataset of Project Linework.  Screenshot/proof: http://i.imgur.com/wS8WbS9.png

Comment: That's it exactly. You rock! Did you recognize it or were you able to find it by searching? Thanks

Comment: I recognized it. The guy that does the website has a few different cartography/GIS blogs that I read.  https://cartastrophe.wordpress.com/ & https://somethingaboutmaps.wordpress.com/ . Also he was the editor for these 2 books which have some really beautiful cartographic design. I own both volumes: http://atlasofdesign.org/

Answer (score -1):

This might help out. It's a link to what appears to be all state boundaries.

https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f7f805eb65eb4ab787a0a3e1116ca7e5

Comment: The question asks for a site that produces artistic rather then geographically accurate outlines, so I don't think the actual outlines from ESRI are likely to help very much.